# Comparing Numbers when those Numbers are String and Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators

In excel the cell A1=0 and A2 cell =0 and the format is Text .

=A1>A2 is False whereas, =A1less than A2 is True.

Can anyone explain that how the values are compared and return the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want compare the number. Try `=Value(A1)<Value(A2)`